# How to use JavaScript or jQuery to wrap the selected text into a web page in a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I need to find a way to wrap the selected (highlighted) text in a web page into a specific tag using javascript or jQuery. I managed to wrap some text into the tag, but the problem is that whenever my selection includes two different paragraphs, the selected text becomes new paragraphs (i.e. everything becomes a mess). This is what I got (I am using the code inside a Google Chrome extension):

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var rng = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var wrappingNode = document.createElement("myElement");
wrappingNode.appendChild(rng.extractContents());
rng.insertNode(wrappingNode);
```

I'm trying to find a way to prevent messing up the web page structure. Do you guys have any idea??

My objective is to apply a specific css style to this selected text.

Thank You!

Comment: The code is inside a Chrome Extension

Comment: "Everything becomes a mess"? Sounds like a CSS issue. When you add a new Node to the beginning of your `Range` Object, that could affect something. ie: `.someclass:first-child{}` `first-child` in `.someclass` would now be your new Node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FF only example because of `range.createContextualFragment` but something to work with. got to get to sleep!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .highlight {color: red; }
    </style>
    <script>
        function highlight() {
            var text, sel, range;
            if (window.getSelection) {
                text = window.getSelection().toString();
                sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.rangeCount) {
                    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    range.deleteContents();
                    range.insertNode(range.createContextualFragment('<span class="highlight">'+text+'</span>'));
                }
            } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
                text = document.selection.createRange().text;
                range = document.selection.createRange();
                range.innerHTML = '<span class="highlight">'+text+'</span>';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<p>lorem ipsum donor kebab</p>
<button onclick="highlight()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```